# Scaling a 32 bit random number to get it into specific range?

Tags: arm, keil

In ARM assembly
how does one go about scaling a 32 bit random number to get a number between 4.0-25.0?

All I can think of is extracting first five bits and work with that but that is not really scaling...

I'm looking for something like multiplying and dividing the 32 bit number to get it into that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique you want to implement is something like this (in `C`):

```
float scale (u32 v)
{
    return  (float) v / 0xffffffffL * (25 - 4) + 4.0;
}
```

Since the denominator is constant, it could be rewritten using only multiplication, if speed is important.

Comment: if v is a 32 bit random number than lets say for example u have FFFF FFFF which is a really big number then dividing that by (25-4) then adding 4 would not result in the range of 4-25

Comment: @mitp:  Yep.  Serves me right answering a "brain required" question so late at night.  I have updated it with a *better* answer.

Answer (score 0):

wallyk answered it but this is just grade school stuff, write the two fractions down and solve for the unknown.

```
x/y = a/b

rand/0xFFFFFFFF = a/21

(rand/0xFFFFFFFF)*21=a;
```

Then you add 4 to a.

and you could do this if it is accurate enough for you

```
(rand/204522252.143)+4.0
```

The compiler might optimize that for you though if you write the code right

```
x=((rand/((double)0xFFFFFFFF))*21.0)+4.0;
```

or

```
x=((rand/4294967295.0)*21.0)+4.0;
```